# How to get values from a checked list box and input into textbox

Tags: c#, foreach, checkedlistbox

Basically I am creating an app for a Deli as a project assignment for my C# class. What I wanted to know is basically how to get a value from a `CheckedListBox` using a `foreach` loop and using an `if` statement to set a numeric number for an item in the `CheckedListBox`, from there I want to have the value entered into a `TextBox`.

Logically, I have a list for add on items for an order such as lettuce and tomatoes. If I want them to cost 25 cents each per add-on and let the user see those values as total cost added in a `TextBox`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
     //adding the amount of money for the add on prices
    private void clbxAddonsT_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach( object item in clbxAddonsT.CheckedItems)
        {
            if (item == "Lettuce" ) //on
            {
                txtOrderSubtotal2.Text = "0.20"; //adding value into textbox
            }
        }
    }
```

I think my issue is that I'm getting the indexes wrong in the `foreach` loop as I don't know exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you please explain your problem more in detail?

Comment: If every selected item is 25 cents, cant you just calculate the subtotal as (Number of checked checkboxes) * 0.25? If different items have different values, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that each add on costs 0.25 cents and you want to display the total inside a text box (why a total displayed in a text box anyway?) here's how you should do:

```
var totalAddOns = 0.0;
foreach (object item in clbxAddonsT.CheckedItems)
{
     totalAddOns += 0.2;
}
txtOrderSubtotal2.Text = totalAddOns.ToString("0.00");
```

You don't have to check the item name is "lettuce" (each add on costs 0.20) and you don't have to udpate the textbox inside the loop as the sum is not yet complete. You have to store the sum in a local variable and display it after you finish looping the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If each checked item costs 0.25 you can just multiply the count:

```
private void clbxAddonsT_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtOrderSubtotal2.Text = (clbxAddonsT.CheckedItems.Count * 0.25).ToString();
}
```

Or if the items have different prices you could do something along these lines:

```
private void clbxAddonsT_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtOrderSubtotal2.Text = clbxAddonsT.CheckedItems.Cast<string>()
                                                     .Sum(i => this.GetPrice(i))
                                                     .ToString();
}

private double GetPrice(string item)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case "Lettuce":
            return 0.25;
        case "Tomatoes":
            return 0.20;
        default:
            return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Also, I think you want to use the `ItemCheck` event as opposed to `SelectedIndexChanged`. This will only fire when an item is about to have its check status changed. You then need to add the new item to checked items yourself before performing calculation:

```
private void clbxAddonsT_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    var checkedItems = clbxAddonsT.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();

    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        checkedItems.Add(clbxAddonsT.Items[e.Index].ToString());

    txtOrderSubtotal2.Text = (checkedItems.Count * 0.25).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert txtOrderSubtotal2.text to int add with 0.20 and then convert to string:

```
     foreach( object item in clbxAddonsT.CheckedItems)
            {
                if (item == "Lettuce" ) //on
                {
                    int total =0;
                    int.tryParse( txtOrderSubtotal2.Text,out total);
                    txtOrderSubtotal2.Text = total + 0.20 + ""; //adding value into textbox
                }
            }
```